# Web-scraping investment fund data into Pandas

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping, pandas, beautifulsoup

Just starting out trying to do some python for data analysis. I am a total beginner and have figure out how to brute force somethings, but I know it is inefficient but don't know how to do it without messing up what i have.

I have multiple webpages to scrape and then store data in a data frame. The code is identical for all of the pages. How do I set it up as a routine instead just repeating the same code over and over again.

As an example the two urls are: https://etfdb.com/etf/IWD/ https://etfdb.com/etf/IWF/

The html is identical so the web scraping working exactly the same for both.

Once scraped, I want them in a single data frame.

The below works, but is me taking the least sophisticated approach since I know so little. The actual code is likely not pretty but it works.

Any help appreciated on how this should be improved.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

iwd_url = 'https://etfdb.com/etf/IWD/'
uClient = uReq(iwd_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Isolate header to get name and symbol
h1 = page_soup.h1

#Isolate stock symbol
title = h1.findAll("span",{"class":"label-primary"})
titlet = title[0].text

#print(titlet)

#strip space and line break
strip1 = h1.text.strip()

#strip stock symbol
strip2 = strip1.strip(titlet)

#strip remaining line break
strip3 = strip2.strip()

#print(strip3)

IWD = page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"chart base-table"})[1]
#Create lists to fill
sectordata=[]
sectorname=[]
sectorweight=[]
for row in IWD.findAll("td"):

    sectordata.append(row.text)
#list created    

#Assign every other value to proper list to get 2 columns
sectorname = sectordata[::2]
sectorweight = sectordata[1::2]

#Insert name/symbol for clarification/validation
sectorweight.insert(0,titlet)
sectorname.insert(0,strip3)

# create empty data frame in pandas
df = pd.DataFrame()
#Add the first column to the empty dataframe.
df['Sector']  = sectorname

#Now add the second column.
df['Weight'] = sectorweight
##display(df)

### NEXT

iwf_url = 'https://etfdb.com/etf/IWF/'
uClient = uReq(iwf_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Isolate header to get name and symbol
h1 = page_soup.h1

#Isolate stock symbol
title = h1.findAll("span",{"class":"label-primary"})
titlet = title[0].text

#print(titlet)

#strip space and line break
strip1 = h1.text.strip()

#strip stock symbol
strip2 = strip1.strip(titlet)

#strip remaining line break
strip3 = strip2.strip()

#print(strip3)

IWD = page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"chart base-table"})[1]
#Create lists to fill
sectordata=[]
sectorname=[]
sectorweight=[]
for row in IWD.findAll("td"):

    sectordata.append(row.text)
#list created    

#Assign every other value to proper list to get 2 columns
sectorname = sectordata[::2]
sectorweight = sectordata[1::2]

#Insert name/symbol for clarification/validation
sectorweight.insert(0,titlet)
sectorname.insert(0,strip3)

# create empty data frame in pandas
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
#Add the first column to the empty dataframe.
df2['Sector']  = sectorname

#Now add the second column.
df2['Weight'] = sectorweight
#display(df2)

results = df.merge(df2, on = "Sector")
results.columns = ['Sector', 'IWD', 'IWF']
display(results)
```

Like I said, this works, but it isn't automated and its ham-handed way of getting there. Please help me to get better!

Answer (score 1):

I created function `get_soup` because this code is offen used many times in code. In this code I could put all in `get_data`.

`get_data` gets `url` and uses `get_soup` with this `url`. Later it scrapes data from html, creates DataFrame and returns it

Main part uses `get_data` with two urls and gets two dataframes.

I put some other comments in code.

```
# <-- remove not used modules
# <-- use more popular names 
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

# --- functions ---
# <-- all functions before main part

def get_soup(url):
    # <-- more readable names (and more popular)
    response = urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    response.close()
    soup = BS(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


def get_data(url):

    soup = get_soup(url)

    #Isolate header to get name and symbol
    h1 = soup.h1

    #Isolate stock symbol
    # <-- find() to get only first item
    title = h1.find("span",{"class":"label-primary"}).text

    #print(title)

    #strip space and line break
    # <-- use the same variable instead strip,strip2, strip3
    # <-- maybe too much comments 
    header = h1.text.strip()

    #strip stock symbol
    header = header.strip(title)

    #strip remaining line break
    header = header.strip()

    #print(strip)

    # <-- use better name 'table'
    table = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"chart base-table"})[1]

    #Create lists to fill
    #sector_data = [row.text for row in table.find_all("td")]
    sector_data = []
    # <-- remove lists which will be created later

    for row in table.find_all("td"):
        sector_data.append(row.text)

    #Assign every other value to proper list to get 2 columns
    sector_name = sector_data[::2]
    sector_weight = sector_data[1::2]

    #Insert name/symbol for clarification/validation
    sector_weight.insert(0, title)
    sector_name.insert(0, header)

    # create dataframe in pandas
    # <-- create DF directly with data
    df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Sector': sector_name,
       'Weight': sector_weight,
    })

    #display(df)

    return df

# --- main ---

# <-- the same variable `url` because it keep the same type of data
#     and I will no need this value later - so I can resuse this name.
url = 'https://etfdb.com/etf/IWD/'
df1 = get_data(url)

url = 'https://etfdb.com/etf/IWF/'
df2 = get_data(url)

results = df1.merge(df2, on="Sector")
results.columns = ['Sector', 'IWD', 'IWF']
display(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) allows to

> Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.

Using this we can store the urls in a list.

```
l=['https://etfdb.com/etf/IWD/','https://etfdb.com/etf/IWF/']
```

Then we read the urls and store them in a list:

```
dfs=[pd.read_html(i)[5].rename(columns={'Percentage':i.split('/')[-2]}) for i in l]
```

---

Once we have this list of dataframes, we can use a reduce merge to merge all the dataframes in the list:

```
from functools import reduce
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Sector'), dfs)
print(df_final)
```

---

***Output***

```
                    Sector     IWD     IWF
0               Financials  23.02%   3.21%
1               Healthcare  12.08%  14.04%
2              Industrials   9.27%   9.39%
3                   Energy   8.98%   0.35%
4   Consumer, Non-Cyclical   8.85%   4.69%
5           Communications    7.7%  11.27%
6               Technology   6.13%  36.46%
7       Consumer, Cyclical   5.86%  14.24%
8              Real Estate   5.15%   2.31%
9                    Other   3.54%   2.55%
10         Basic Materials   2.74%   1.34%
11      ETF Cash Component   0.33%   0.14%
```